# External drive does not spin down when unplugged

Tags: external-hard-drive, usb-storage

I have a [Captiva USB3-SATA bridge](http://www.captiva-power.de/captiva-hdd-35-usb3-en.html), which contains an [asmedia ASM1053](http://www.datasheetspdf.com/datasheet/ASM1053.html) chip. It spins down when it is plugged into the server after 10 minutes idle time, but it spins indefinitely when the server is not running or the USB cable is not plugged. Is it possible to fix this somehow?

Comment: An interesting question. I don't think it is related to the enclosure/bridge though. It's most likely a general question of ATA drives (maybe even SCSI drives too). You'll probably experience the same issue when it's connected to your PSU but not to a SATA port. I wonder if any ATA drive is capable of spinning down when it has only power but not data connection.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to stop it spinning is to turn the power off to the Captiva USB3-SATA bridge, I have a USB drive and it behaves the same way.